# Can't seem to get MySQL up and running on Node.js with express ( Have only used WAMP/MAMP before )

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I'm using express with Node.js. Installed MySQL globally with this command :

```
npm install -g mysql
```

Afterwards I included this in my app.js file :

```
var mysql = require('mysql');

var db = mysql.createConnection({
    host        :'localhost',
    user        :'root',
    password    :'root',
    database    :'nodejs'
});

db.connect(function(err) { 
    if (err) throw err; 
    console.log("Connected!"); 
});
```

Unfortunately, I get an error :

```
ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3306
```

No clue what am I supposed to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you have not installed `MySQL` (database server).

With this command:

```
npm install -g mysql
```

That you did is install the [npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql) (as global) that only is a javascript "wrapper" to use in node.js for communicate with `MySQL`, but see that you have not installed `MySQL`.

To install `MySQL` take a look to this [link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/installing.html)

The install of `MySQL Server` depends on what operative system are you using and usually you use a system command, or an executable installer (in Windows), but never npm.

Comment: Shouldn't I already have it installed considering I have MAMP?

Comment: Yes, if you have installed MAMP, is a package that has MySQL, but your error is due to there is nothing listening on port 3306. Maybe check mamp and mysql configuration, probably are you using another port